# Bulk insert with validation in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm inserting objects in bulk to MongoDB using Mongoengine like this (simplified code):

```
class Customer(Document):
    first_name = StringField(max_length=100)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=100)
    address = StringField(required=True)

instances = [Customer(**{'name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'})]
Customer.objects.insert(instances)
```

I'm bulk inserting using list Document instances created from dicts. As you can see on the above example, the Customer instance lacks required `address` field. However, it is saved in the MongoDB anyway. Then in the MongoDB there is a Customer document without the required field `address`.

**My question:** What can I do so that the schema is validated when bulk inserting? Is a *for loop* and calling `instance.save()` for each Customer instance my only alternative?

---

In the [MongoEngine documentation](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/validation.html?highlight=validate#document-validation) it is written:

> By design, MongoEngine strictly validates the documents right before
> they are inserted in MongoDB and makes sure they are consistent with
> the fields defined in your models.

so I'm confused why using `objects.insert()` does not validate the document.
However, later [in the docs](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/validation.html?highlight=validate#built-in-validation) it is written:

> Validation runs when calling .validate() or .save()

so maybe by design `objects.insert()` does not validate documents and before bulk inserting there should be a loop going through all instances and calling `validate()`?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Customer.objects` what's returned is actually a `QuerySet`. The `QuerySet.insert` (docs [here](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.insert)) method has no option for validation unfortunately.

Your idea to pre-validate and bulk insert seems like the best option:

```py
instances = []
for instance in [{'name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'}]:
    customer = Customer(**instance)
    customer.validate()
    instances.append(customer)

Customer.objects.insert(instances)
```

This is much faster than calling `save` on each instance.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the response

Comment: Hi @C. Braun, could you help me about `.validate()` method, what is exactly the result from that method, because I need to check it first if that raise ValidationError I need to assign some value to a list of failed record

Comment: Hey @rails_id it's described [here](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.validate). You can call `.validate()` on your document and catch any `ValidationError` it throws. If you want the specific errors, you can call `.to_dict()` on the exception.